# How to find all longest words in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

If I have a string with no spaces in it, just a concatenation like  `"hellocarworld"`, I want to get back an array of the largest dictionary words. so I would get `['hello','car','world']`.  I would not get back words such as `'a'` because that belongs in `'car'`.

The dictionary words can come from anywhere such as the dictionary on unix:

```
words = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words").collect{|x| x.strip}

string= "thishasmanywords"
```

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Assume "loca" was in your dict. How would that affect your result?

Comment: loca would also be found along with hello, car,and world.

Comment: And a dict entry "he"?

Comment: Please some effort into answering your own question before posting on here. SO is not a place where people do all your work for you.

Comment: if loca is allowed, then all valid words such as 'a' and 'he' and 'i' must be allowed also, so any valid word in the dictionary.  at the end I would filter out anything less than 3 letters.

Comment: I think you are saying you want to construct an array `a` of all substrings (runs of adjacent characters) `s` such that: 1. `s` is in the dictionary and 2. no element of `a` is a substring of any other element of `a`.  Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a bit tricky if you're not familiar with the technique. I often lean heavily on regular expressions for this:

```
words = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words").collect(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)
regexp = Regexp.new(words.sort_by(&:length).reverse.join('|'))

phrase = "hellocarworld"

equiv = [ ]

while (m = phrase.match(regexp)) do
  phrase.gsub!(m[0]) do
   equiv << m[0]
   '*'
  end
end

equiv
# => ["hello", "car", "world"]
```

**Update:** Strip out blank strings which would cause the `while` loop to run forever.

Comment: I think this solution will only work for simple cases like the one provided. If the OP wants to find all the longest words possible (so an N-length word is worth more than any number of (N-1)-length words), this may not be enough. Take a look at my comment under the other answer. 
Not to mention the monstrous regex. I'd rather go for checking substrings of the word against the dictionary kept in a collection with less than linear search time combined with a B&B-type algorithm. This code has taken minutes to execute on my Mint VM and it doesn't show signs of stopping yet.

Comment: From a computer-science perspective, yes, this is a really obnoxiously complicated thing to solve correctly. On the other hand, the "good enough" approach like what I've posted here will get you 99% of the way there without fouling things up too badly. It produces one solution of many, converging quickly on what might end up being a suboptimal one. An important caveat to note, though, good observation on your part. Regular expressions are fairly well optimized as a state machine, so evaluation of a fairly simple, if large one, is not necessarily impossibly slow.

Comment: I'm not saying it's slow just by looking at the code (although I fully expected it to be). I've just run it and it bogged down my machine till it almost stopped responding, at which point I killed the process... and all it did was search for the longest words in `"hellocarworld"`. To be fair, I haven't compared it to any other solution just yet.

Comment: @tom It runs in 1.2s on my machine on `"hellocarworld"`. That loop should stop matching eventually and quit. It's possible there's a blank line in your dictionary that's causing a perpetual match. I've added a patch for that.

Comment: could be the case. I'll check it when I have a moment to spare.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following.

**Code**

For a given `string` and dictionary, `dict`:

```
string_arr = string.chars
string_arr.size.downto(1).with_object([]) { |n,arr|
  string_arr.each_cons(n) { |a|
    word = a.join
    arr << word if (dict.include?(word) && !arr.any? {|w| w.include?(word) })}}
```

**Examples**

```
dict = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words").collect{|x| x.strip}

string = "hellocarworld"
  #=> ["hello", "world", "loca", "car"]

string= "thishasmanywords"
  #=> ["this", "hish", "many", "word", "sha", "sma", "as"]
```

"loca" is the plural of "locus".  I'd never heard of "hish", "sha" or "sma".  They all appear to be slang words, as I could only find them in something called the "Urban Dictonary".

**Explanation**

```
string_arr = "hellocarworld".chars
  #=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "c", "a", "r", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
string_arr.size 
  #=> 13
```

so for this string we have:

```
13.downto(1).with_object([]) { |n,arr|...
```

where `arr` is an initially-empty array that will be computed and returned.  For `n => 13`,

```
enum = string_arr.each_cons(13)
  #<Enumerator: ["h","e","l","l","o","c","a","r","w","o","r","l","d"]:each_cons(13)>
```

which enumerates over an array consisting of the single array `string_arr`:

```
enum.size                #=> 1
enum.first == string_arr #=> true
```

That single array is assigned to the block variable `a`, so we obtain:

```
word = enum.first.join
  #=> "hellocarworld"
```

We find

```
dict.include?(word) #=> false
```

so this word is not added to the array `arr`.  It is was in the dictionary we would check to make sure it was not a substring of any word already in `arr`, which are all of the same size or larger (longer words).

Next we compute:

```
enum = string_arr.each_cons(12)
  #<Enumerator: ["h","e","l","l","o","c","a","r","w","o","r","l","d"]:each_cons(12)>
```

which we can see enumerates two arrays:

```
enum = string_arr.each_cons(12).to_a
  #=> [["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "c", "a", "r", "w", "o", "r", "l"],
  #    ["e", "l", "l", "o", "c", "a", "r", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]]
```

corresponding to the words:

```
enum.first.join #=> "hellocarworl"
enum.last.join  #=> "ellocarworld"
```

neither of which are in the dictionary.  We continue in this fashion, until we reach `n => 1`:

```
string_arr.each_cons(1).to_a
  #=> [["h"], ["e"], ["l"], ["l"], ["o"], ["c"],
  # ["a"], ["r"], ["w"], ["o"], ["r"], ["l"], ["d"]]
```

We find only "a" in the dictionary, but as it is a substring of "loca" or "car", which are already elements of the array `arr`, we do not add it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the beginning of the input string, find the longest word in the dictionary. Chop that word off the beginning of the input string and repeat.

Once the input string is empty, you are done. If the string is not empty but no word was found, remove the first character and continue the process.

Comment: Algorithmically that's going to be brutally slow due to the number of cycles required.

Comment: How would you go about conflicting words of the same length? Take the string `"exploiterate"`. You can extract either `"exploit"` or `"iterate"`, which have the same length. If you extract `"exploit"`, you can still use `"ate"`. If you pick `"iterate"`, you can use `"lo"`.  It's not just a matter of picking the first longest word you find. Also, searching the whole dictionary sounds slow. A better approach would be to validate consequent substrings of the string (from longest to shortest) against the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I sketched a very naive search algorithm here.